# Private конструктор

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор

Можно ли создать объект, если конструктор имеет модификатор `private`? Если да, то зачем собственно конструктору нужен модификатор доступа?

Comment: только если через метод в этом классе:)

Answer (score 7):

Это нужно, когда объект создается функцией-фабрикой (статической) того же класса. Часто, после создания объекта необходимо вызвать какой-либо его метод (например, для инициализации, которая не может быть выполнена в конструкторе), без вызова которого объектом нельзя пользоваться.

Answer (score 5):

Приватный конструктор запрещает создание экземпляра класса вне методов самого класса, например, что гарантировать существование только одного объекта определённого класса, предположим какого-то ресурса, например БД.

Подробнее про паттерн [Singleton (Одиночка)](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/singleton/java/example)

Answer (score 3):

можно. чтобы создавать только из статических методов данного класса. сделать что-то типа фабрики.

Answer (score 2):

Создать можно через статический метод фабрику, это делается для того чтобы не создавать объекты напрямую, чтобы именовать конструкторы, но так же можно создать такой объект через рефлексию.

UPD

Ещё такие классы с приватными конструкторами используют для создания утилитарных классов, в которых есть только static методы.

Answer (score 1):

Модификатор доступа `private` определяет доступ в рамках данного класса, где вы можете создавать объекты. Т.е. вы не сможете создать объект этого класса за его пределами, так например с помощью `new` из другого класса или блока.

Конечно если вы не используете рефлексию, которая может изменить положение вещей.

Зачем это нужно, ну скажем вы хотите контролировать создание объектов внутри класса.

Answer (score 1):

Это может делаться в том случае если для работы с классом не нужны его объекты: яркий пример утильные классы в которых все методы статические для работы с которыми объекты класса не нужны. К примеру класс java.util.Collections, который определяет вспомогательные методы для работы с коллекциями. Покопайтесь в нём и Вам всё станет понятно. Как говорится "Больше тысячи слов". 
Повторюсь: модификатор private конструктору нужен, для того чтобы снаружи класса нельзя было создавать объекты через этот конструктор и им можно было пользоваться только внутри самого класса, а применений масса.